# Changing the size of files

Tags: bluetooth, thumbnails

When sending files through bluetooth, it doesn't expand the image I click, so that I can be sure of the image I want to send.

Is there any settings to change that ?

EDIT : As GabrielaGarcia mentioned : "Open with file manager" seems to be inactive
[image]

Comment: No, there isn't but you can check the files in the file manager before sending.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia
Can't do that....Edited the question with the problem. Can you explain please ?